# Remove a container in XML

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

This is my input file .Deliberately left the headers out as I thought they don't concern the question.I have not pasted the whole file as it is huge.I have added only two containers:

```
  <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
     <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
     <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject</DEFINITION-REF>
     <PARAMETER-VALUES>
       <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
         <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue</DEFINITION-REF>
          <VALUE>1053</VALUE>
       </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
       <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
       <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANHandleType</DEFINITION-REF>
           <VALUE>TRUE</VALUE>
        </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
      </PARAMETER-VALUES>        
<ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>

    <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
     <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
     <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject</DEFINITION-REF>
     <PARAMETER-VALUES>
       <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
         <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue</DEFINITION-REF>
          <VALUE>1054</VALUE>
       </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
       <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
       <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANHandleType</DEFINITION-REF>
           <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>
        </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
 </PARAMETER-VALUES>        
<ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
```

I have around 100 `<ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>` tags in my xml . I have to delete `<ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>` container if the text of the `<DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF">` container below it is `/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue`
But I am not getting the result.Kindly help.

The script I have written:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
tree = ET.parse('a.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for child in root.findall(".//ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUE"):
    for gchild in child.findall(".//DEFINITION-REF [@DEST='ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF']"):
         string = gchild.find("VALUE").text
         if string == "/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue":
             root.remove(child)
```

Comment: I agree, I don't see a reason to downvote. However, it would be helpful to have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The XML in your question is not well-formed since it doesn't have a single root element. (I haven't checked to see if there are any other issues yet.) Can you update your XML to be well formed? It is especially important to include any default namespaces (`xmlns="..."`) in the ancestors of `ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE`.

Comment: @DanielHaley Thanks for the input . I did not paste the whole file .I have added only two containers . Edited .

Comment: Did my answer help or are you still having issues?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove `ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES`, you need to select it's parent. So try doing your iteration from the `PARAMETER-VALUES` level.

Example...

**XML Input** (`a.xml`; updated to be well-formed)

```xml
<doc>
    <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
        <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
        <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject</DEFINITION-REF>
        <PARAMETER-VALUES>
            <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
                <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue</DEFINITION-REF>
                <VALUE>1053</VALUE>
            </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
            <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
                <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANHandleType</DEFINITION-REF>
                <VALUE>TRUE</VALUE>
            </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
        </PARAMETER-VALUES>
    </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
    <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
        <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
        <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject</DEFINITION-REF>
        <PARAMETER-VALUES>
            <ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
                <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue</DEFINITION-REF>
                <VALUE>1054</VALUE>
            </ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES>
            <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
                <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANHandleType</DEFINITION-REF>
                <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>
            </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
        </PARAMETER-VALUES>
    </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
</doc>
```

**Python**

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('a.xml')

for p_vals in tree.findall(".//PARAMETER-VALUES"):
    for num_p_vals in p_vals.findall(".//ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES"):
        def_ref = num_p_vals.find("DEFINITION-REF[@DEST='ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF']")
        if def_ref is not None and def_ref.text == \
                "/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue":
            p_vals.remove(num_p_vals)

ET.dump(tree)
```

**Output**

```xml
<doc>
    <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
        <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
        <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject</DEFINITION-REF>
        <PARAMETER-VALUES>
            <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
                <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANHandleType</DEFINITION-REF>
                <VALUE>TRUE</VALUE>
            </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
        </PARAMETER-VALUES>
    </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
    <ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
        <SHORT-NAME>ABC</SHORT-NAME>
        <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-PARAM-CONF-CONTAINER-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject</DEFINITION-REF>
        <PARAMETER-VALUES>
            <ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
                <DEFINITION-REF DEST="ECUC-ENUMERATION-PARAM-DEF">/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANHandleType</DEFINITION-REF>
                <VALUE>FALSE</VALUE>
            </ECUC-TEXTUAL-PARAM-VALUES>
        </PARAMETER-VALUES>
    </ECUC-CONTAINER-VALUE>
</doc>
```

If you're able to use lxml, it has much better XPath support than ElementTree. You're also able to access the parent element with `getparent()`. In my opinion this simplifies the answer.

Example... (same input as above produces the same output as above)

```py
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('a.xml')

for num_p_vals in tree.xpath(".//ECUC-NUMERICAL-PARAM-VALUES[DEFINITION-REF[@DEST='ECUC-INTEGER-PARAM-DEF']='/AUTOSAR_CAN/EcucModuleDefs/CanConfigSet/CanHardwareObject/CANIdValue']"):
    num_p_vals.getparent().remove(num_p_vals)

etree.dump(tree.getroot())
```